# React&Redux - Erro Feathers-Rematch snapshotPlugin

Tags: javascript, react, redux

Estou auxiliando no desenvolvimento de um "APP" utilizando ReactJS e Redux, FeathersJS...

Todo o projeto roda 100% no Mac, porém ao dar um git pull e executar no Windows o projeto apresenta problema do snapshot, plugin do Feathers-Rematch...

Alguém já teve esse tipo de problema poderia auxiliar...

Biblioteca utilizada..:

```
import { init, realtime, snapshot, auth } from 'feathers-rematch/dist/feathers-rematch.esm.js';
```

Err..:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at Object../src/feathers.js (feathers.js:52)

Linha de código..:

> 52 | const snapshotPlugin = snapshot();

Comment: O erro ao que parece é especifico do pacote, é uma boa tu abrir um `issues` no repositório dos desenvolvedores.

Comment: Se for possível reproduza o erro em um código que possa compartilhar conosco por inteiro para que possamos te auxilar da melhor forma possível, antes de apontar o dedo para biblioteca alheia eu realmente gostaria de saber como está seu código, bom chutando completamente (Já que não dá para entender muita coisa com esse trecho minusculo de código) tive um problema parecido ao usar um objeto como uma função, em resumo eu simplesmente esqueci o new rs, caso Snapshot seja um objeto deve ser instanciado com const snapshotPlugin = new snapshot();